# Generating typings for JS object generates duplicate entries for a function

Tags: typescript

I have a js file that, when generating types, leads to duplicate entries for each function in the object.

`test.js`

```
const test = {
  /**
   *
   * @param {string} testID
   * @returns {void}
   */
  initialize(testID) {
    // I do nothing
  },
};

export default test;
```

`test.d.js`

```
export default test;
declare namespace test {
    /**
     *
     * @param {string} testID
     * @returns {void}
     */
    function initialize(testID: string): void;
    /**
     *
     * @param {string} testID
     * @returns {void}
     */
    function initialize(testID: string): void;
}
```

What gives?

Comment: I think that you should report it as a bug: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the declaration `initialize(testID)` vs `initialize = function(testID)`

This will generate perfectly:

```
const test = {
  /**
   *
   * @param {string} testID
   * @returns {void}
   */
  initialize: function(testID) {
    // I do nothing
  },
};

export default test;
```

yields:

```
export default test;
declare namespace test {
    function initialize(testID: any): void;
}
```